# What's being said in this YouTube video about lifting weights?

Tags: listening

What is this guy saying at 13:34 to 13:45 in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bs_Ej32IYgo)? I do understand about the hip, and hamstrings parts, but rest of em kinda unclear to me.

Comment: Welcome to ELL! At times the videos are so noisy for even native speakers to understand what's being said, so you don't need to lose confidence when you don't hear what people mumble.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because ELL is not a transcription service

Comment: Fumble, I didn't ask you for a transcription service. You seem to have a chip on your shoulder regarding this question.

Comment: SAO, no one has a chip on their shoulder. This question *is* asking for transcription, though.

Comment: I asked this question in order to improve my listening skills, and I was having a trouble to understand what the guy saying in this video until I got the answer below. I don't know this can be still transcription propose, but I really learned something by posting this question. Hopefully, some people not confuse propose between learning and a personal gain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[13:20] ... "Now let's talk about a controversial topic: Proper Depth. You didn't think I'd make an entire how to squat video without mentioning depth did you? Proper depth is achieved when the crease of your hips goes below the top of your kneecap."

[13:35] "I don't want to hear about how you hit parallel or went below parallel or your thighs are parallel, your hamstrings are parallel, your femur was parallel, I don't care."

[13:45] "If the crease of your hips goes below the top of your kneecap, it's a good squat. If the crease of your hips does not go below the top of your kneecap, it was not a good squat. Period."